# Javascript json objects get with string

Tags: javascript, json

Can i navigate my json with string values? y.z return undefined

```
var x = '{ "ALGO_TL": { "lowestAsk": 8.488,"highestBid": 8.391 } }';

var y = JSON.parse(x);

var z = "ALGO_TL";

console.log(y.ALGO_TL); // { lowestAsk: 8.488, highestBid: 8.391 }

console.log(y.z); // undefined
```

Comment: `console.log(y[z]); // defined`

Comment: Thanks, simple :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the bracket notation:

```js
var x = '{ "ALGO_TL": { "lowestAsk": 8.488,"highestBid": 8.391 } }';
var y = JSON.parse(x)
var z = "ALGO_TL";

console.log(y[z]);
```